# Installing Xen Hypervisor as a direct to metal hypervisor

Tags: xen

I want to install Xen hypervisor as a bare metal hypervisor without first installing an operating system. Is this possible, everything I read seems to imply that it was, but I can only find instruction on how to install it on an existing operating system such as windows or linux. Does one need an OS simply to get it on the machine, after which it operates directly as dom 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading multiple questions here so let me get at them one after the other:

### 1. is it possible to install Xen to any  (existing) OS such as Windows or Linux?

No. Xen employs a model where it relies on a privileged Domain (Dom0 [1]) for certain services the hypervisor cannot do itself.
To run more than one Guest, Dom0 must emulate certain things like the BIOS and manage shared hardware such as the sound-card.

Currently there is no way to simply Boot windows from xen, since Xen will not provide the necessary Boot parameters to the Windows bootloader (which is not multiboot[2] compatible).

### 2. Do you need an OS simply to get it on the machine?

No you can/could install xen directly from a Linux Live CD, then again technically this is an OS, so yes with limits.

[1] http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/Dom0
[2] http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html

Answer (score 1):

For your Question on weather Xen is a bare metal Hypervisor you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100949/xen-bare-metal-hypervisor) 
Initially I was really confused on Bare Metal Hypervisor (Even now I am not so clear) But I after I installed Citrix XEN Server and XenClient (both are proprietary) you actually can see the difference (xenclient should be installed in Windows) This will actually help you to install and control the VM's centrally. Hope I can be of some help :)

Comment: Just want to mention that I am not in any way supporting Citrix. I even hate the idea of installing xencenter on Windows only :P . Jst wanted to tell this :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that you have to reboot the machine and switch to the xen kernel after you install the hypervisor ? So, in this sense, the hypervisor is running as a bare metal hypervisor. If you really want to install it without a existing operating system, then try xenserver  from citrix. There is a free version and can be got from citrix's website.